# Auto Hyperlink the extracted files

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a code which can extract entire path of a pdf files and display of active workbook.
But problem is the extracted files are not hyperlinked i.e. I cant open the files directly on clicking on the that cell. Is there any way it gets automatically hyperlinked so that one click opens the files directly from excel.

Below is the code:

```
Sub ReadFiles()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("C1").Value)

i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If Right(objFile.Path, 3) = "pdf" Then
   'print file path
    Cells(i + 2, 13) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
End If
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, replace "WorksheetName" with the name of your worksheet:

```
Sub ReadFiles()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("C1").Value)

i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If Right(objFile.Path, 3) = "pdf" Then
   'print file path
    Cells(i + 2, 13) = objFile.Path
    Sheets("WorksheetName").Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:= Sheets("WorksheetName").Cells(i + 2, 13), _
    Address:= objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
End If
Next objFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After you print file path add this:                                          `cells(i + 2,13).select                                    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, ActiveCell`

Comment: It's good to avoid using the `.Select` function when writing code in VBA as it tends to slow down the macro.